# How to continuously receive and parse the JSON from REST API in spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring

There is a remote server keep bringing about the data in JSON format. Here is a REST API named
**http://192.168.1.101:8000/v1/status**,and if I want to collect the data continuously in Spring Boot.Here is a possible JSON from the REST API:

```js
{
"run-status": 0,
"opr-mode": 0, 
"ready": false, 
"not-ready-reason": 1, 
"alarms":["ps", "prm-switch"] 
}
```

I want to keep collecting or just subscribe the REST API, if there is a JSON and then collect it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main approaches of achieving what you are looking for:

1. Polling - If this service already exists and you do not have control
   over the code, then this might be your only option.  You constantly
   poll the given URL to check if data has been changed.

   In spring, you can use `@Scheduled` annotation to execute and poll
   at any given frequency (using cron expression or fixed delays).

   https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks - provides a detail
   of how to create a scheduled tasks.
2. Webhooks - If you have control over your server code, you can use
   webhooks to notify subscriber about availability of data.  It is a
   callback mechanism where caller will receive a notification about
   data changes on the server, and subscriber can then call server to
   fetch data immediately.

More about Polling and Webhooks can be found on this URL: https://dzone.com/articles/webhooks-vs-polling-youre-better-than-this-1

Answer (score -2):

Make a "while" cycle what calls your function then goes to sleep (if needed) for the time you want.

Or just while (true) {}